# Keyboard Access and Dialog Box Buttons

Tags: macos, keyboard, dialog

After upgrading to Catalina from High Sierra. I found that I can no longer use the enter key in place of the mouse to click on dialog box buttons. Keyboard access and navigation is currently enabled in keyboard settings.

Comment: How about if you disable Full Keyboard Access in accessibility preferences?

Answer (score 0):

@Tom Gewecke I didn't have a chance to test disabling Full Keyboard Access but I was running brew cleanup, update, and upgrade for my homebrew apps and found that the problem resolved itself.  I am not sure it had anything to do with it and only the virtualbox and rectangle apps were affected by the commands.  I'll try disabling Full Keyboard Access, if it happens next time.